# Is there a way to test Triggers with mocks?

Tags: trigger, unit-test

When I write triggers, I try to follow best practices by implementing them according to the Separation of Concerns principle. This design pattern allows me to encapsulate logic and separate it from my trigger. The problem I run into is how to test a trigger without also testing logic from dependent classes. Take this example below:

```
trigger AccountTrigger on Account (after insert) {

    if(Trigger.isAfter)
    {
        if(Trigger.isInsert)
        {
            Foo foo = new Foo();
            if(foo.isTriggerable){
                foo.execute(Trigger.new);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This trigger works, but there is no way to test it without also testing the logic encapsulated in the Foo class. My trigger only cares about whether it should call or shouldn't call `foo.execute()`. So it shouldn't need to test that logic contained in that method.

In other programing languages, I would test this by mocking the Foo class and calling something like `foo.execute.shouldBeCalled()`. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a way to do this in Apex.

I've considered using static variables to mimic what a mock would do, but I'd love to hear how other people where able to get around this (even if it's not elegant). I'm aware you can mock HTTP callouts, is there also a way to mock classes and methods?

Comment: Note that as the trigger is `after insert` the `Trigger.isAfter` and `Trigger.isInsert` are redundant. (Perhaps you included them to just bulk out the example?)

Comment: @KeithC, in this example it is redundant. Just using it to demonstrate my point.

Comment: On your question, my view is that the coupling between code moved out into a separate class and the trigger contexts - isInsert/isUpdate/isDelete/isUndelete combined with isBefore/isAfter plus triggers causing each other to run - is more significant than is sometimes implied. So testing triggers and their logic as a whole by inserting/updating/deleting/undeleting objects rather than trying to mock anything is more cost effective. But I will be interested to see the answers you get.

Comment: note that a trigger framework such as https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Trigger_Frameworks_and_Apex_Trigger_Best_Practices eliminates all code in the trigger except for a call to a handler